# Is there any way to get one side(i.e., right bordered line) of the jtextfield colored

Tags: java, swing, border, jtextfield

Hi I prepared one swing frame in which I placed two text fields. Is there any way to get one side(i.e., right bordered line) of the jtextfield colored? Please suggest. I checked many things, but I couldn't find.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would add a Border to the text field, something along the lines of:

```
Border oldBorder = jTextField.getBorder();
Border redBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 5, Color.RED);
Border newBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(redBorder, oldBorder);
jTextField.setBorder(newBorder);
```

This approach keeps the old border and wraps it inside your red (partial) border.

Comment: cleaner than the other answer, although I don't think that OP needs to keep the original border.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob. As I apply only the matteBorder, the textfield is losing it's original border too and displaying only one sided red border and looking like a line rather than text field. But your answer avoided that scenario.

Answer (score 9):

In the example below I added a left side border of 5 pixels:

```
JTextField jtf = new JTextField();        
jtf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
```

This is a right side border:

```
jtf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 5, Color.BLACK));
```

I hope this is what you are after

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own `CustomBorder` class by extending from the `Border` class and creating your own custom border for your component. Set it by calling `setBorder()` on your `Component`'s instance something like:

```
class MyBorder implements Border {

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component cmpnt, Graphics grphcs, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        //draw your border here
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component cmpnt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Reference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html

Comment: Why the **Question Mark** at the very end ? This is not making any sense. Though +1 for Custom Border :-)

Comment: Lol it was a questionated suggestion :)

Comment: While providing snippets, much wise would be to use proper names instead of **i/i1/i2/i3**, better to use, **int x, int y, int width, int height**, so that it conveys the message, without more thoughts :-)

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)